# Why attributes order on product pages are showing in alphabet order, if I set them as 'menu_order' in the admin bar?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

In admin bar on wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes&edit=4 I set sorting by menu order, in attribute values I set them in order I need manually.
But when I add values in single product, they are adding in alphabet order, like M, XL, XS, so as they showing on the product page like that.
How can I change their order like I need? (XS, S,M,L,XL)?
My theme is fully custom, not a child of some ready theme.
Maybe I need to add some code to fix it? Or the issue is in admin bar?
[image]

Comment: I have tested with clean Woocommerce install and attributes are sorted properly. Theme used storefront - https://prnt.sc/2390c67

Comment: I found the problem - one of variation swatches plugins. Who could  think! Before it worked correctly. Installed another one. That's why I prefer pure code, not plugins, except woocommerce itself and different integrations with payment and socials....